# simple jQuery code is not executed when rendering django template

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I want to hide a table row based on its class. Everything is working fine except the js file is not executed and I cannot hide the table row. What is the problem?

**html file:**

```
{% extends "heaven/home.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}

<script src="{% static '/js/hide.js' %}"></script>
```

**hide.js**

```
$('.cemeteryRow').hide();
```

hide.js sits in static/js folder. Class=cemeteryRow.

Comment: what about `<script src="{% static 'js/hide.js' %}"></script>`

Comment: Always check what is outputted as HTML code in your browser. As suggested by @Messaoud Zahi, you might have 2 slashes.

Comment: You may also have a required block for `content` defined.  If so, make sure your `script` tag appears in the content block.

Comment: Thanks guys for the suggestions, but I could not get them work. Let me explain a bit more so that you can get a better idea: for home url I print a table with 3 rows. I have 3 urls say A, B and C and when the request is url A I want to only show row 1 of that table, when url B, row 2 only and so on. I think I can include an if condition on the block content, where I print the table. Do you have any idea how it can be done?